# How do I use a websocket in Meteor?

Tags: node.js, meteor, websocket

I'd like to have the Meteor server make a connection to another computer running a websocket; however, I can't figure out how to call the 'ws' module.

`Meteor.require('ws')` and `requite('ws')` don't seem to work, and I've tried a few other things without any real results.

In the current release of Meteor, how do I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently Meteor uses SockJS for the websockets that DDP establishes. You won't have access to this version of SockJS in your app though because it's a package dependency and therefore is stored in the node_modules folder for the DDP package. You can however install any websocket library you would like and use it.

`meteor npm install --save ws` will install ws and then you can just import and use it.

```
import WebSocket from 'ws';
```

Comment: How can I use it then? After import, `WebSocket` is just an empty object.